# how to redirect ckan to external url unless authorized or signed in

Tags: adfs, ckan

How can i go about redirecting ckan to a external URL unless logged in?

I added the following code below in ckan/logic/auth/get.py under the method site_read

```
if context.get('auth_user_obj') is not None:
    return {'success': True}
else:
    return {'success': False, 'msg': 'User not logged in. Pleaes authenticate with AD.'}
```

But i only get as far as just saying permission denied on each page unless logged in. Is there a way i can make it just redirect to an external url if not signed in or authenticated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Implement [IRoutes interface](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IRoutes)

In the before_map function check if a user is logged in, if not use map.redirect to your external URL.

Comment: But how do you get the current logged in user ?