# Approach for preveting annomyous access to CKAN site

Tags: ckan

I have a CKAN site running with the ckanext-ldap extension configured, but I only wan't authenticated users to be able access the site.

This is my solution so far, but I'm not totally satisfied:

```py
import ckan.plugins as plugins
import ckan.plugins.toolkit as toolkit

def site_read(context, data_dict):
    # List of allowed paths, when not logged in
    allowed_anon_paths = ['/user/login', '/ldap_login_handler']

    # Prevent "site read" if the user is not logged in and the
    # request path is not in the list of allowed anonymous paths
    if not context.get('user') and toolkit.request.path not in allowed_anon_paths:
        return {'success': False}

    return {'success': True}

class Disable_Anon_AccessPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IAuthFunctions)

    def get_auth_functions(self):
        return {'site_read': site_read}
```

It prevents anonymous users from accessing any pages (other than login related), but it provides a 403 Forbidden error, on all pages until logged in.

(also API requests fails with 500 error, unless logged in or providing an API key, but I can live with that)

I can't figure a way to redirect, to the login page, if not logged in and/or making the "remember me" feature work.

Adding something like: toolkit.redirect_to('/user/login') instead of return {'success': False} does not have an effect.

I also looked into the IRoutes interface, but I cannot figure out how to get the current logged in user (or checking if a user is logged in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the following approach used in CKAN to prevent non-logged in access to the site.

It uses the `IMiddleware` plugin interface:

```
class AuthMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app, app_conf):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # if logged in via browser cookies or API key, all pages accessible
        if 'repoze.who.identity' in environ or self._get_user_for_apikey(environ) or not is_iar():
            return self.app(environ,start_response)
        else:
            # otherwise only login/reset and front pages are accessible
            if (environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/' or environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/login' or environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/_logout'
                                or '/user/reset' in environ['PATH_INFO'] or environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/logged_out'
                                or environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/logged_in' or environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/logged_out_redirect'):
                return self.app(environ,start_response)
            else:
                # http://rufuspollock.org/2006/09/28/wsgi-middleware/
                environ['wsgiorg.routing_args'] = '',{'action': 'login', 'controller': 'user'}
                return self.app(environ,start_response)

    def _get_user_for_apikey(self, environ):
        # Adapted from https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/625b51cdb0f1697add59c7e3faf723a48c8e04fd/ckan/lib/base.py#L396
        apikey_header_name = config.get(base.APIKEY_HEADER_NAME_KEY,
                                        base.APIKEY_HEADER_NAME_DEFAULT)
        apikey = environ.get(apikey_header_name, '')
        if not apikey:
            # For misunderstanding old documentation (now fixed).
            apikey = environ.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '')
        if not apikey:
            apikey = environ.get('Authorization', '')
            # Forget HTTP Auth credentials (they have spaces).
            if ' ' in apikey:
                apikey = ''
        if not apikey:
            return None
        apikey = unicode(apikey)
        # check if API key is valid by comparing against keys of registered users
        query = model.Session.query(model.User)
        user = query.filter_by(apikey=apikey).first()
        return user
```

Which is then added to your plugin class, e.g.

```
class Disable_Anon_AccessPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IMiddleware, inherit=True)

    def make_middleware(self, app, config):
        return AuthMiddleware(app, config)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - exactly what I'm looking for, only thing I can can't get working is the "remember me" feature

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few ways to achieve this.

Probably the easiest. You could try something like this [suggestion to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51223813/3366016) check if a user is logged in on every page and redirect if not. But this let's people know a site is there and attempt logins.

You could break out some authentication and put it on a gateway/load balancer/reverse proxy in front of the app and authenticate there (I've seen similar is azure with an app gateway running nginx with azure AD).

If you're using LDAP I'm guessing you might have a local network (intranet possibly?). You could just set it behind that as well. Or create a firewall that blocks access unless specific network or IP block.

[Another suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932651/3366016)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've already tried authenticating using basic auth, but that approach doesn't really works, because the user has to be in the local user table (thats the benefit of the ckan ldap extension, because it creates the user, if it doesn't exist). Regarding blocking on IP level, that won't really be a good solution in this case.